# Sending an email through app; any way will do

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xcode4.2

Here is the code that I have for my cell of my  UITableView:

```
                            forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Title", @"Cells", @"Footer Title", nil]] autorelease];
[tableView1CellData addObject:sectionContainer_3];
NSMutableArray *cells_4 = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
NSDictionary *cellContainer_4_1 = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Support", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"1", nil]
```

What would I have to add so that when the cell is tapped, it happened up a MailView in the app (preferably) but I understand that the easiest way is to just use the HTML "mailto" ? I'm brand new to Objective-C, but I am able to edit C and C++, so I think that I can work in any answer.  Thanks in advance!

P.S.  Posting this from iPhone (just thought of asking question) so sorry if the code isn't highlighted, but i tried to space it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Add the [Message UI Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MessageUI_Framework_Reference/_index.html)

2.You should have registered a delegate for the UITableView. See a UITableView tutorial if needed.

3.Implement the following method:

```
- (void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath { 
    ... 
}
```

4.Inside the method use MFMailComposeViewController to send the email. Example usage:

```
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller setSubject:@"My Subject"];
[controller setMessageBody:@"Hello there." isHTML:NO]; 
if (controller) [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

Read More: [How can I send mail from an iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310946/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-iphone-application)

[UITableView/UITableViewCell tap event response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889200/uitableview-uitableviewcell-tap-event-response)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the documentation on [`MFMailComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html). You can present a mail compose view, user will fill it out and send the mail.

Comment: Using the code above, though, how would I do this?  I'm confused by the documentation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

And yes, you *can* use the `mailto:` URL thing... but @jer's answer is the one I would prefer to do myself, as a developer.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto://info@iosdevelopertips.com"]];
```

(details for the above can be found at http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-other-apps-within-an-iphone-application.html)

Comment: Yes, this is more clear then the documentation, but how would I connect it to thr cell?

Comment: the code snippet you put into your question isn't detailed enough for me to figure out where you're putting your e-mail addresses or how the table view cell is being filled out.